# php pack: problems with data types and verification of my results

Tags: php, pack

I am PHP beginner and my task is to build commands which will later be sent over UDP to a device. Running: OSX, PHP 5.5.3.8
To create the binary data I am using "pack". Here is an example of my code:

```
<?php
$in_1 = 0x3100;
$in_2 = 0031;
echo "Inputs: " . $in_1 . "\t" . $in_2;
$bin = pack("v*", $in_1, $in_2);
echo "\nlength: ". strlen($bin);
printf ("\npacked result: %x \n",$bin);
printf("HEX result %h\n", $bin);
file_put_contents("ausgabe.log", $bin, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

the output in my terminal is:

```
Inputs: 12544   25
length: 4
packed result: 0 
HEX result
```

I wonder about the number 25 for $in_2. 
If I assign 0x0031 to $in_2 the result is 49. 
Whats wrong here?

By the way: My final goal is to build binary commands which are exactly 12 Bytes in a scheme like this (decimal values as comments in each line):

```
function set_routing_item ($in_ch, $out_ch, $on_off, $seq)
{
    $command = toggle_two_bytes(37);    // 37 --> 0x2500
    $status = 0x0000;                   // 0 --> 0x0000
    $pos = 4;                           // 4= route item
    $channel_1 = $in_ch;                // 3
    $channel_2 = $out_ch;               // 6
    $preset_no = 0xff;                  // 255
    $value = $on_off;                   // 33145
    $seq = $seq;                        // 35
    // implement building of command using pack here
}
```

The result in this case(hex) should look like: 25 00 00 00 04 03 06 FF 79 81 23 00

Thanks!

Comment: Okay First thing solved. PHP interprets numbers with leading zeros as Octal number. So $a = 0123; is equivalent to 83 decimal
Example found here: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Can you post more information about ``toggle_two_bytes``

Comment: Of course. Although I learned with correct modifier 'v' in pack() this isn't necessary anymore...
    // toggle higher and lower byte of a two-byte short variable
    function toggle_two_bytes ($two_bytes)
    {
        $two_bytes = $two_bytes & 0xffff; // limit size to 2 Bytes
        $high = ($two_bytes << 8);          // bit shift
        $low = ($two_bytes >> 8);
        $ret = ($high | $low);              // OR
        $ret = $ret & 0xffff;               // limit (again) to two bytes
        return ($ret);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this, but it is **not** the best method to do it, proper bitwise operations would be faster.

I'm using `sprintf` with the `%x` format specifier which converts the value to a hexadecimal value.

> Each conversion specification consists of a percent sign (%)

You will see I use `%02x` and `%04x`

- `0` - Left-pads the number with zeroes
- `2` or `4` - Width, the minimum number of characters to be printed.
- `x` - Specifier for hexadecimal, use `X` for uppercase.

Code:

```
<?php
function toggle_two_bytes ($two_bytes)
{
    $two_bytes = $two_bytes & 0xffff;   // limit size to 2 Bytes
    $high = ($two_bytes << 8);          // bit shift
    $low = ($two_bytes >> 8);
    $ret = ($high | $low);              // OR
    $ret = $ret & 0xffff;               // limit (again) to two bytes
    return ($ret);
}


function set_routing_item ($in_ch, $out_ch, $on_off, $seq)
{
    $str  = '';
    $command = toggle_two_bytes(37);
    $str .= sprintf('%04X', $command);

    $status = 0x0000;
    $str .= sprintf('%04X', $status);

    $pos = 4;
    $str .= sprintf('%02X', $pos);

    $str .= sprintf('%02X', $in_ch);

    $str .= sprintf('%02X', $out_ch);

    $preset_no = 0xFF;
    $str .= sprintf('%02X', $preset_no);

    $value = toggle_two_bytes($on_off);
    $str .= sprintf('%04X', $value);

    $seq = toggle_two_bytes($seq);
    $str .= sprintf('%04X', $seq);

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str) - 1; $i += 2) {
      echo $str[$i] . $str[$i+1] . ' ';
    }
}

echo set_routing_item(3, 6, 33145, 35) . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
25 00 00 00 04 03 06 FF 79 81 23 00
```

Demo: https://eval.in/793695

Comment: Thanks for your inspiration. I finally got the `pack()`to work. The _magic_ is in here:
`return pack("vvCCCCvv", $command, $status, $type, $ch, $out_ch, $preset, $value, $seq);` To see my result I use `bin2hex()` on the bin string. 
Cheers! Stefan.

Comment: BTW I checked the string that I sent via UDP with wireshark- everything is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad formatted answer. 
Here is the requested code:

```
// toggle higher and lower byte of a two-byte short variable
function toggle_two_bytes ($two_bytes)`

{
    $two_bytes = $two_bytes & 0xffff; // limit size to 2 Bytes
    $high = ($two_bytes << 8);          // bit shift
    $low = ($two_bytes >> 8);
    $ret = ($high | $low);              // OR
    $ret = $ret & 0xffff;               // limit (again) to two bytes
    return ($ret);
}
```

I found out that with pack('v',...) this is not necessary anymore.