# PHP pack: do not really understand

Tags: php, pack

I posted this ([php pack: problems with data types and verification of my results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884823/php-pack-problems-with-data-types-and-verification-of-my-results)) and found that I had two problems. 
So here again only one issue (I solved the other one) Hopefully this is easy to understand:
I want to use the PHP  pack() function.
1) My aim is to convert any integer number info a hex one of length 2-Bytes.
Example: 0d37 --> 0x0025

2) Second aim is to toggle high / low byte of each value: 0x0025 --> 0x2500
3) There are many input values which will form 12-Bytes of binary data.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to lookup the format table in the [pack() manual page](https://secure.php.net/pack) and it is quite easy.

2 bytes means 16 bits, or also called a "short". I assume you want that unsigned ... so we get `n` for big endian (high) and `v` for little endian (low) byte order.

The only potentially tricky part is figuring out how to combine the format and parameters, as each format character is tied to a value argument:

```
bin2hex(pack('nv', 34, 34)) // returns 00222200
```

If you need a variable number of values, you'll need agument unpacking (a PHP language feature, not to be confused with `unpack()`):

```
$format = 'nv';
$values = [34, 34];
pack($format, ... $values); // does the same thing
```

And alternatively, if all of your values should be packed with the same format, you could do this:

```
pack('v*', $values); // will "pack" as many short integers as you want
```

Comment: My calculator says 37dec is 0x25... Anyway you lead me to the core of the problem: If I echo the pure binary data echo (and I assume printf as well) interpret these data as char and print the ASCII character. Looks like bin2hex() did the trick to display the data. I think I am fine now thanks a lot!

Comment: Indeed ... I had typed in 34 instead of 37 everywhere. Don't know what I was thinking.